# How to escape whitespace in variable passed to cd

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I am using WSL on windows 10 with Ubuntu.
The path to a directory I use frequently includes a directory with a space in the name. I can't change that name.
The path to the directory is very long:
 `/mnt/c/Users/name/Dropbox/My PC (Laptop...)/Desktop/Studies/Python`
So I would like to create a variable in .bashrc by the name of `$PROJECTPATH` that would be equal to the directory's path.
That way I could call or alias `cd $PROJECTPATH` and get to my files.
I tried writing:

```
PROJECTPATH='/mnt/c/Users/name/Dropbox/My\ PC\ \(Laptop...\)/Desktop/Studies/Python'

alias prjct='cd $PROJECTPATH'
```

but when running prjct I'd get the error message "too many arguments" which means there's a space being passed to cd.
How could I escape whitespaces when passing a variable to cd or any other command?
And should I export this kind of variable?

Comment: This effect is called [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Splitting). See [this entry in the bash-hackers.org wiki](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words#word_splitting)

Comment: @glennjackman Worked perfectly :). Many thanks!

Comment: `alias a='builtin cd "$b";:'` you can terminate your alias with `:` or `true` this will suppress any additional arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put double quotes around `$PROJECTPATH` in your `alias` definition.

Also, I recommend against backslashes in your variable definition. It's less readable and isn't needed in this case:

```bsh
PROJECTPATH='/mnt/c/Users/name/Dropbox/My PC (Laptop...)/Desktop/Studies/Python'

alias prjct='cd "$PROJECTPATH"'
```